# Error to fetch the Publish Date from Microsoft URL

Tags: extract

traying so much method but won't be able to fetch the Date.

!pip install htmldate

Using the htmldate library to fetch the date from Microsoft page

Extract date using various classes below.
date_classes = ["post-date","entry-date","date", "postmeta-date","single__meta"]

for class_name in date_classes:
date_element = soup.find(class_=class_name)
if date_element:
return date_element.get_text(strip=True)
except (requests.exceptions.RequestException, AttributeError, TimeoutError):
pass
except AssertionError:
print("AssertionError occurred. Ignoring.")

```
return None
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PGY7y.png)